# visual studio code command not working on wsl2, only when trying to create new file

Tags: visual-studio-code

For some strange reason, whenever I try to create a new file from the command line visual studio code it does not work:

For example:

`code hello.txt` does not work. But if I want to open a directory with `code .` it does work. I already tried uninstalling vscode but it did not work as well.

P.S: This happens inside wsl2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue here. As a workaround, you could add

```sh
new() {
    touch $1
    code $1
}
```

to `~/.bashrc`, and open new files with `new filename`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue, just started today.
Oddly enough:

```
touch hello.txt
code hello.txt
```

Seems to work fine. Could potentially create a shortcut for that. Although the concern is if there's a setting that was inadvertently misconfigured.

Comment: yes I think I will open a bug report. I know about `touch` but I'm lazy :)